# Identifying Clicked Button in Preview Modal When Performing Print Operation with react-to-print

Tags: reactjs, react-to-print

I want to perform a print operation using react-to-print and I want to know which button (print or cancel) is clicked in the opened preview modal for this operation. How can I do that?

I tried using the beforeprint and afterprint methods, but they don't work for my purpose.